# EBS: aborted deployment when EC2 still exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I try to deploy a zip on EBS. There is one EC2 and the environment health is green and seems to be fine. I try to deploy a zip and I get:

```
ERROR   During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'xxx'. Aborting the operation.
```

I deploy 10 zip's but all the same issue. I even tried to redeploy the zip which is also deployed at the moment (tried several times) but even that is not possible. What could be the issue?

Some configuration:

```
 Environment type: Load balanced, auto scaling
Number instances: 1 - 1  (tried 1-2, and 0-2)
 Instance type: t2.medium
```

I can only deploy succesfully if I terminate the ec2's manually and start a new deployment before the ec2's are scaled up again.

Comment: Please post the entire contents of `/var/log/eb-activity.log`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Couldn't deploy old builds or even the current one. It suddenly started working after a while, seems like an temporary issue with AWS.